# $X$ and $Y$ independent random variables such that $X$ and $X+Y$ be independent ($X$ not constant)

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, independence

**Question :**

Let's $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables such that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, and $X$ not constant.

> Can $X$ and $X+Y$ be independent? If yes, when?

($X$ and $Y$ don't necessarily have an expected value)

**My attempt :**

$X$ and $X+Y$ independent would mean for all $x\in X(\Omega)$ and $z\in (X+Y)(\Omega)$, $P(X=x,X+Y=z)=P(X=x)P(X+Y=z)$ and we know (by independence of $X$ and $Y$) that $P(X=x,X+Y=z)=P(X=x)P(Y=z-x)$.

So we must have, for all $x$ such that $P(X=x)\neq 0$,
$$P(X+Y=z)=P(Y=z-x)$$
And $P(X+Y=z) = \sum\limits_{x\in X(\Omega), y\in Y(\Omega), \ P(X=x)\neq 0 \text{ and } x+y=z} P(X=x)P(Y=z-x)$.
So if $P(X+Y=z)\neq 0$, $\sum\limits_{x\in X(\Omega), y\in Y(\Omega), \ P(X=x)\neq 0 \text{ and } x+y=z} P(X=x) = 1$.

So for all $z$ such that $P(X+Y=z)\neq 0$ :
$$\forall x\in X(\Omega), P(X=x)\neq 0, \exists y\in Y(\Omega), x+y=z$$

But then I don't really know what it implies, and can't find an example.

Can someone help me?

**Edit :**

Mrsami has given a beautiful answer in the case where $X$ has finite second moments. But the case where this is not true is still not solved.
Every one that has an idea to tackle it (with basic tools if possible) is welcome.

Comment: This may help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1224083/are-x-and-xy-independent-if-x-and-y-are-independent

Answer (score 6):

Suppose $X$ and $X+Y$ are independent. Then
$$
E(X(X+Y))=E(X)E(X+Y)=(EX)^2+E(X)E(Y)
$$

On the other hand
$$
E(X(X+Y))=E(X^2+XY)=E(X^2)+E(XY)=E(X^2)+E(X)E(Y)
$$

Necessarily, one must have
$$
(EX)^2=E(X^2)
$$
i.e.,
$$
\textrm{Var}(X)=E((X-EX)^2)=E(X^2)-(EX)^2=0
$$
which implies that $X$ is a constant (almost surely). A contradiction.

---

Notes.

This answer assumes all the random variables have finite second moments (and hence are absolutely integrable). In general, pathological (such as not absolutely integrable) random variables are handled in an *ad hoc* way. I believe you will need to search among the usual pathological examples such as [Cauchy distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution). But I don't have such an example off-hand.

Comment: I upvoted but what if the random variables don't have an expected value ?

Comment: Maybe we can choose two applications $f$ and $g$ such that $f(X)$ and $f(Y)$ have an expected value, ... but I'm not sure.

Comment: @math: yes, this answer assumes all the random variables have finite second moments.  In general, pathological (such as not absolutely integrable) random variables are handled in an ad hoc way.

Comment: Could you detail a bit ? I tried and didn't find how to do it (when $X$ has no expected value)

Comment: Ok. But can we find an example for discrete variables?