# Generating random variables with sum zero

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

I was trying to generate a random vector $(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n)$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i =0$. There is also an underlying assumption that every proper subvector of this vector is independent (like $X_1,\ldots,X_{n-1}$ are independent, or $X_2,\ldots, X_n$ are independent).   But I am unable to generate this; in fact, I think it is not possible to do so. 
Suppose we take $n=3$. We generate $X_1, X_2$ (so they are independent) and take $X_3 = -(X_1+X_2)$. But this contradicts the underlying assumption that $X_1,X_3$ are independent. Because we should have $X_1, X_3$ independent as well, and this is not possible from [Are $X$ and $X+Y$ independent, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1224083/are-x-and-xy-independent-if-x-and-y-are-independent).  
Is my reasoning correct or is the way I am generating such variables wrong? Any help or reference would be grateful.

Comment: It is indeed impossible to generate such a random vector, and your reasoning is basically correct. What is possible is to introduce "almost independence" for sufficiently large $n$, since the interaction between $X_i$'s which is imposed by the constraint $\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i=0$ becomes smaller if $n$ becomes larger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, it is impossible to have $X_1,\dots,X_n$ be *pairwise uncorrelated* while summing to zero always, except in the case where the variables are all constant zero. This is a much weaker assumption than requiring any proper subset of variables to be independent.

Suppose that $X_1+\dots+X_n=0$, and that the variables are pairwise uncorrelated. This implies that
$$
0=\text{Var}(0)=\text{Var}(X_1+\dots+X_n)=\text{Var }X_1+\dots+\text{Var }X_n
$$
But if the sum of variances is zero, then all the variances must be zero. Therefore, the only example is the trivial case where each variable is a deterministic constant, such that these constants sum to zero.

Comment: They don't have to be zero; they just have to be constants that add to zero.